# i have 2 table 1 table have 1 column with unique key and another table with multiple unique key column

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, left-join, inner-join

table 1

| status_id | detail_id | region_id | cust_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0000 | 1212 | 1112 | jack |
| 0101 | 2222 | 1113 | jill |

table 2

| value_id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 0000 | request |
| 0101 | done |
| 1212 | pending |
| 2222 | reprocess |
| 1112 | north america |
| 1113 | europe |

desired result

| status | detail | region | cust_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| request | pending | north america | jack |
| done | reprocess | europe | jill |

i tried with this query, is there any other methods ?

```
select 
b.value AS status,
c.value AS detail,
d.value AS region,
a.cust_name
from table1 a
left join table2 b ON a.status_id =b.value_id
left join table2 c ON a.detail_id = c.value_id
left join table2 d ON a.region_id = d.value_id;
```

Comment: Is it possible to split table 2 into multiple tables based on the type of information contained?

Comment: I think your query is the good one.

Comment: The only other method would be to change the design; you should really have your region, status and detail values in *different* tables.

Comment: What's wrong with your query?  I don't see anything wrong with it.  I bet it will give you the result you want.

Comment: the query work just fine. Im just wondering is there any other method,cause i find it kind of ridiculous to join the same table multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is appropriate for the given task. You should not use table aliases, though, that don't carry meaning. a, b, c don't tell us anything and it's easy to confuse these. Use mnemonic aliases instead, like s for statuses, d for details and r for regions.

But there is a problem with your data model. As you are using one table for different things, you cannot guarantee data integrity. While you can say that a status_id, a detail_id and a region_id must be found in the values table, the DBMS does  not know which row is which. Thus it can happen that you store a row with status = north america, detail = europe and region = pending without the DBMS interfering. Change your database and create one table per entity to get this straight and have the DBMS help you write consistent data.